# Draggable always goes to the outermost sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, nested-sortable

I'm trying to write a page where users can drag items into one of three nested, sortable UL. No matter where the user drops the draggable, it always lands on the outer(or topmost) UL. I've whipped up a simplified version that illustrates the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vexxecon/2q72M/3/).

I am not able to target the ULs by id, as the ids are determined at runtime. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Might want to re-think your html structure, getting kinda convoluted which is probably the issue jQuery UI is having.

Comment: I think you're right, but I don't have a lot of options due to project requirements. The only other method I can think of is to create the same sort of thing with divs, but I'd end up in the same snag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript events bubble up. Since your sortables are contained inside eachother, the event is bubbling to your first(inner-most) sortable, then the event bubbles up to the second sortable, and so on until it is finally captured by the last(outer-most) sortable. You can prevent the event from bubbling further up by adding `event.stopPropigation()` into your sortable receive function.

Comment: I tried this on the jsFiddler, no dice. Also, I think setting the 'greedy' option to true is supposed to accomplish the same thing - works with droppable, but not draggable.

Comment: i got it to work by changing the tolerance: 'pointer' option, but it is still VERY finicky. In the meantime, i did see this. works wonderfully: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424652/jquery-connecttosortable-nested-lists-and-greedy-option

Comment: The link got me thinking in the right direction, so ...close enough.